# Special IF/THEN Statement And Data Validation List In VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The best way I can explain what I need is this:

- If `A1 = ""` and `A3 = ""`, then put a data validation list in cell A2.
- If `A1 = ""` and `A3 <> ""`, then `A2 = A3`.
- If `A1 <> ""` and `A3 = ""`, then `A2 = A1`
- If `A1 <> ""` and `A3 <> ""`, then `A2 = A1`

I know I'm leaving out a lot of information, but if anyone could write this in VBA Code where it automatically updates when A1 or A3 are changes, I would appreciate it. I already have a named range that I want to use for the Data Validation List. I am working in Excel 2016, but I need this to work with Excel 2010 as well. I know, quite literally, nothing when it comes to coding.

Edit:

If it were possible to write this in a formula in cell A2, it would go as follows:

`=if(and(A1="",A3=""),Named_Range,if(and(A1="",A3<>""),A3,if(and(A1<>"",A3=""),,A1,if(and(A1<>"",A3<>""),A1,""))))`

Whereas "Named_Range" would make the cell a data validation list with the named range `"Example 1"`. In every other instance, the data validation list would be deleted and would equal the respective cell.

However, I know that this is not possible (I think) without using Worksheet Change in VBA Code. I am not familiar with writing VBA code, but I do know you can write If/Then statements and Data Validation Lists in VBA code. I just need to make that "Formula" in VBA Code in excel.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want code to add data validation to your sheet, either in A1, A2, or A3. For that you need a code writing service which you won't find on this site. Here you can find help after you tried to write the code yourself and it somehow doesn't quite work as you had hoped.

Comment: If you are just getting started, check out WiseOwl Tutorials for VBA on YouTube. They do a great job going over a lot of topics. Feel free to ask a follow up once you've had a chance to study up, the SO community is always willing to help :)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-coding solution you could add two additional rows (and swap row 2 & 3) to allow for the automation:

Row 1: Values

Row 2: Values

Row 3: `=if(and(A1="",A2=""),"SELECT FROM DROPDOWN BELOW",if(and(A1="",A2<>""),A2,if(and(A1<>"",A2=""),,A1,if(and(A1<>"",A2<>""),A1,""))))`

Row 4: Dropdown list where the first option is blank ""

Row 5: `=IF(A3<>"SELECT FROM DROPDOWN BELOW", A3, IF(A4<>"",A4,"SELECTION NEEDED"))`

Much taller, but fits the given requirements.